# Two rings A and B are isomorphic. Then $End_A(M) \cong End_B(M)$ for every A and B Modul M.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ring-isomorphism

Hi I found this Lemma without a proof in a script: If two rings A and B are isomorphic with $\Phi A \to B$. And M is an B-Leftmodul then M is also an A-Leftmodul with with $A \times M \to M: am \mapsto \Phi(a)m $. Then $End_A(M) \cong End_B(M)$ as Rings. The first part is clear but why are the endomorphism rings isomorphic? My guess what be that the Isomorphism is the identity and for $a\in A, f \in End_B(M), m\in M, f(am)=f(\Phi(a)m)=\Phi(a)f(m)=af(m)$. So these rings are identical. Is that correct?

Comment: Indeed, viewed as rings, they are not just isomorphic, they are identical (same set of maps $M\to M$, same addition, same multiplication). Nevertheless, this only holds if we view the endomorphisms as naked maps; if we view them explicitly as $A$- or $B$-module endomorphisms (as in: deliberately attach such a "label" to the maps), we need to formulate carefully that the rings are *canonically isomorphic* and not really identical. It's a matter of perspective, so to speak

Comment: Thank you very much. I understn that there is a difference between A and B-Modules so there is a difference between these rings. How can I define these canonical isomorphism?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, sounds good enough for an answer.  Though I'm not sure I agree about needing to make the canonically isomorphic distinction.  I think as you've stated the maps are equal and those maps are both $A$-module and $B$-module maps, that they carry both labels doesn't necessitate a distinction between the objects.